# Integrate TFS with HP ALM

Tags: tfs, dashboard, alm

How to integrate TFS with HP ALM to retrieve the Test Metrics and display it on TFS Dashboard ?

We maintain our Test cases in HP ALM and defects in TFS. I'm looking for some solution to display the Test Metrics details (like Daily Execution status along with defects for all the releases) in TFS dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OpsHub Integration Manager](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-integration-manager/) to Integrate TFS with HP ALM, however it's not free, you need to buy license.

Please see below articles for more information:

- [HP ALM/QC Integration with TFS](https://www.opshub.com/hpalm-qc-integration/hp-alm-qc-tfs-integration/)
- [Enabling seamless integration with Team Foundation Server, Microsoft
  Test Professional and HP ALM with Opshub v5.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/05/16/enabling-seamless-integration-with-team-foundation-server-microsoft-test-professional-and-hp-alm-with-opshub-v5-3/)

And there is a video talking about that: [TFS Integration with JIRA & HP ALM / HPQC using OpsHub Integration Manager](https://vimeo.com/278614743)

> OpsHub Integration Manager integrates TFS and HPQC bi-directionally.
>   It ensures that all historical and current data is available to each
>   user, in that user’s preferred system, with full context, in
>   real-time. All ‘user stories’ from TFS automatically synchronize to
>   HPQC. The completion of the story and the status of test results in
>   HPQC against these user stories automatically synchronizes to TFS.

Comment: @Nickson Have you resolved the issue by the answer? Is the answer helpful? any update?